# dx command error even when path is set

Tags: android, dx

I want to use dx tool. So I use the following command in terminal

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex sample.jar
```

and I got this error

```
No such file or directory
```

I know i should set environment variable "path" and add /build-tools/x.y.z/dx to it. But even set the path doesn't resolve the error. I should mention that I can run it from /build-tools/x.y.z/ by running the command

```
./dx
```

but i need to access dx from any directory, for my project purpose. I use ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. How can I fix it?

Comment: you should add a **directory** to the `path`, not a **file**. So you add `/build-tools/x.y.z/dx`, which is a path to a **file**, but you should add only `/build-tools/x.y.z`

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: yes, I tried both version and they don't work. But I modify my script which uses this tool and modify dx with (absolute path of dex)/./dx and it works. Thanks for your suggestion